# Why can't I assign a variable inside of isset? - php

Tags: php, isset

Recently, I've attempted to be tricky and assign a variable inside of an isset function.  I tried to do it like so

```
if(isset($accountid =$_POST['Recipient']))
{
    // my code here ... 
}
```

However, when I do this I receive the error

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')'
```

Here is the documentation for isset if you want to reference it in your answer. 
`bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`

This isn't the hugest deal - but I'd be interested to know why I can't do something along those lines!

Comment: `if($accountid=isset($_POST['Recipient'])?$_POST['Recipient']:false){echo $accountid;}`

Answer (score 7):

`isset` is a language construct and not a true function. It is mentioned in the docs:

> Warning
>
> isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result
>   in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined()
>   function.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a statement, this might be the reason. Here is a note I found in php.net manual for isset().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

**isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error.**

Answer (score 0):

You're putting an operation that doesn't return a pointer to a variable in a function that expects one.

Comment: Yes, and what should the point with `if(isset($accountid =$_POST['Recipient']))` instead of `if(isset($_POST['Recipient']))` be anyway?

Comment: This is wrong. If the problem was passing by reference you'd get a different error message, this is about how isset is built into PHP. http://3v4l.org/6v9hh `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /in/6v9hh on line 11`